# Why $scope.init() isn't called if it use body tag?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.2.5. and I have many pages. some pages use html templates that start with div tags, but other pages use html templates that start with with body tags.

I want to call some function to initialize the page when it loads. But the pages with body tags don't call the init method. Why?

```
<div class="row" data-ng-init="init()" ng-cloak>
```

OK.

```
<body  data-ng-init="init()">
```

Not OK.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, any kind of function that is called from the View has to be declared on a scope - this is typically done with a controller:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.init = function(){
  }
});
```

For `<body>`, if the `ng-controller` is not defined on the element, the only place where it could be defined is on the `<html>` tag - do you have it there?

**Second**, you really shouldn't use `ng-init` to initialize things - this is what you can use the controller for. In the example above, just initialize the ViewModel in the controller function - there is no need to separately invoke `$scope.init()` with `ng-init`:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  init();

  // init function here is only for organization purposes
  // it is not exposed on the scope - there is no need to 
  function init(){
    $scope.foo = "bar";
  }
});
```

So, what is the use of `ng-init`?

It is fairly limited - here's what [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) have to say about that:

> The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than `ngInit` to initialize values on a scope.